# Two lists have different memory address but still are referenced

Tags: python, numpy

I've been playing with python arrays for a while, But recently I faced with a weird problem. Here's my code:

```
import numpy as np

myarr = [
    ["s"],
    ["s"],
    ["w"],
    ["p"],
    ["m"],
    ["g"],
    ["c"]
]

newarr = list(myarr)
print(id(myarr))
print(id(newarr))

print(myarr, "myarr")
print(newarr, "newarr")
print("##### starting manipulation #########")

for i in newarr:
    i[0] = "a"

print(myarr, "myarr")
print(newarr, "newarr")
```

My problem is even when I copy the "myarr" array into a new array called "newarr", when I make some changes in the "myarr", or the "newarr", both of them act like referenced arrays (referencing to the same memory address), even though they have different memory id.

I tried it with slicing, or even arr.copy() method, but they both didn't work.

I only can fix it when I use numpy array.

```
newarr = np.array(myarr)
```

Where is my problem?

Thank you in advance:)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to clone or copy a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/how-to-clone-or-copy-a-list)

Comment: You're making a shallow copy, not a deep copy. The inner lists aren't copied, only the outer one is. Check the id's of the inner lists.

Comment: If you know your data has only 2 levels, you can get a deep copy very simply. For example: `newarr = [list(xs) for xs in myarr]`.

Comment: Why the `numpy` import and tag?  You only show lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `deepcopy`

```
from copy import deepcopy

myarr = [
    ["s"],
    ["s"],
    ["w"],
    ["p"],
    ["m"],
    ["g"],
    ["c"]
]

newarr = deepcopy(myarr)

print(myarr, "myarr")
print(newarr, "newarr")
print("##### starting manipulation #########")

for i in newarr:
    i[0] = "a"

print(myarr, "myarr")
print(newarr, "newarr")
```

**Output :**

```
([['s'], ['s'], ['w'], ['p'], ['m'], ['g'], ['c']], 'myarr')
([['s'], ['s'], ['w'], ['p'], ['m'], ['g'], ['c']], 'newarr')
##### starting manipulation #########
([['s'], ['s'], ['w'], ['p'], ['m'], ['g'], ['c']], 'myarr')
([['a'], ['a'], ['a'], ['a'], ['a'], ['a'], ['a']], 'newarr')
```